# R: deal with list, calculate difference between each element value

Tags: r

I have a list called good, I want to calculate the difference between two values within each vector.

```
good[1:2]
[[1]] 
 [1]    8   16   28   38   53
[[2]]
 [1]    1    7    9   16   40
```

so I will get another list

```
good_dif1[1:2] 
[[1]]
 [1] 8 12 10 15 
[[2]]
 [2] 6 2 7 24
```

if I want insert a NA to first value, how can I do that?

so I will get another list

```
good_dif2[1:2]
[[1]] 
 [1] NA 8 12 10 15 
[[2]] 
 [2] NA 6 2 7 24
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `lapply`

```
good <- list(c(NA,1,10,30,40), c(NA,3,4,5,10,20))
lapply(good, diff)
```

For the second part,

```
lapply(good, function(x)c(NA, diff(x)))
```

or

```
Map(c, NA, lapply(good, diff))
```

Hope that Helps.

Comment: Nice. I never thought of using `Map` that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
> good <- list(c(8, 16, 28, 38, 53), c(1, 7, 9, 16, 40)) 
> good_dif1 <- lapply(good, diff)  
> good_dif2 <- lapply(good_dif1, function(x) append(NA, x))
> good_dif2
## [[1]]
## [1] NA  8 12 10 15

## [[2]]
## [1] NA  6  2  7 24
```

Comment: `sapply` gives a matrix as a result in your answer, not a list as you show. I think you mean `lapply` for the second step.

Comment: The result is fine, this is an lapply equivalent using `c()` instead of `append`: `lapply(good_dif1, function(x) c(NA, x))`

Comment: @MartinBel - The result was not fine as it did not match the output shown. Fixed now though. The other answer essentially covers that variation without doing it in two steps.

Comment: The post says that two additional lists (called `good_dif1` and `good_dif2`) are desired.

Comment: I ment that the previous code: `typeof(sapply( lapply(good, diff), function(x) append(NA, x)))` doesn't return a matrix but a list.